# Insert into a db data coming from a loop (while)

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

hi have a code like this

```
for ($i=0; $i<=count($query)+1 ; $i++)
 {
$sql ="SELECT * FROM $tabella[$i] WHERE id='1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$surname=$row['surname'];

INSERT INTO student (name,surname) Values ($name,$surname)
} 

}
```

It insert the data only from the first table he found so only one name and one surname and not all the $name and $surname with id=1

How can I resolve it

Comment: ext/mysql is deprecated. consider switching to a newer library.

Comment: I think you should consider using [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) rather than the while loop.

Comment: replace $sql ="SELECT * FROM $tabella[$i] WHERE id='1'"; for $sql ="SELECT * FROM $tabella[$i] WHERE id=$i";

Comment: Thanks...I'm considering it...but I can't find a way how to SELECT all field of all tables.. I've tried
$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (id,name, surname)
SELECT '',name, surname
FROM $tabella[$i]"; 
but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edit to your script and possible problems I fouund:

```
for ($i=0; $i<=count($query)+1 ; $i++)           //Why is there a +1?
 {
$sql ="SELECT * FROM $tabella[$i] WHERE id='1'"; //Your issue could be here, tabella[$1]
$result=mysql_query($sql);                       //may not be totally there
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);                //Try to echo your SELECT $sql query 
                                                 //to check

                                                 //Why do you have $numrows? I dont see
                                                 //that being used anywhere

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$surname=$row['surname'];

INSERT INTO student (name,surname) Values ($name,$surname) //Your INSERT statement 
                                                           //looks ok
                                                           //Try to use single/or double
                                                           //quotes around the values
                                                           //I like having `name`,  
                                                           //`surname` around fields
} 

}
```

Check with comments. It's recommended you use Prepared/or PDO but in most cases
websites that use straight mysql functions are older or have already been coded so there
aren't any changes of being redone; its a lot of work. This makes sense when you're starting fresh. Hope it helps.